# Add String data to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I have an NSString that gets a new value everytime a cell is clicked i want to add this value to an NSMutableArray, I have tried the following [NSMutableArray addObject:NSString] but this adds the string at the first index value of the NSMutableArray and on click of the next cell it replaces the value that was previously stored. I want to save all the values. How can it be done?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


 UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSIndexPath *tableSelection = [listingSet indexPathForSelectedRow];

if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    [SelectedFiles removeObject:ID];
    NSLog(@"++++++Titlesss %@",SelectedFiles);



    [listingSet deselectRowAtIndexPath:tableSelection animated:YES];
} else { 

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

          ID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[ParsedData valueForKey:@"ID"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

                   [SelectedFiles insertObject:ID atIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@",ID);
        NSLog(@"%@",SelectedFiles);







            [listingSet deselectRowAtIndexPath:tableSelection animated:YES];
}

}
```

This does not seem to work.

EDIT: I read somewhere that my data is being saved on the first index of the array so i would need to increment the index path of the array everytime i save data in it but i am unable to figure out how.

Comment: I'm sure it's working entirely according to spec.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're creating a new array every time. You shouldn't do that. Try making your array a property of your view controller.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *stringElements;
```

In the view controller's init method:

```
self.stringElements = [@[] mutableCopy];
```

And when a cell is tapped:

```
NSString *ID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[ParsedData 
valueForKey:@"ID"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[self.stringElements addObject: ID];
```

Comment: I even tried to do this by declaring the Mutable Array globally and not after the code itself but it does not seem to help

Comment: It should help if you initialize your array for example in your view controller's init method.

Comment: Please check the Edit in the question

Comment: You don't have to increment any index. All you need to do is add the object to the array using addObject:. The object will be added at the end of the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *FileID = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

OR USE

```
   NSMutableArray *FileID = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:3];
```

**Delclare it outside the scope** .This line initialise and provide a new valid memory for the array and each time executing it creates the array.So the added object always remains in the 1st position of new array formed from this line noted above.

so as solution just move this line out of the declared position.Put it in `init` or `viewdidLoad`  or `viewWillAppear` method and that is it .

`addObject:` method adds the object tho the next available position in the `NSMutableArray` so,this will be enough

Make an instace variable

```
@interface ATTDownloadPage ()
{
    NSMutableArray * FileID;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSMutableArray *FileID = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:3];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *ID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[ParsedData valueForKey:@"ID"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [FileID addObject:ID];
}
```

**EDIT**
*From your code*

```
    [SelectedFiles insertObject:ID atIndex:0];
```

causes the problem
.this line replaces the object at index 0 all the time so no value added into the array
Try this in place of the above code

```
 NSMutableArray *tempArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:3];
        [tempArray addObject:ID];
        [tempArray addObjectsFromArray:SelectedFiles];
        SelectedFiles =[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];
```

Comment: Where in question OP talking about loops?

Comment: Please check the edit in the question

Comment: after declaring the nsmutable array in the viewdidload i get an error in didselectrowatindexpath saying Use of undeclared identifier.

Comment: Ok make it an instance variable first.

Comment: @user2417160 Edited the answer try it

Comment: Now in the nslog where i was printing the array it is printing null

Comment: @LithuT.V it didnt work

Comment: add some more code into the qn

Comment: answer edited .Please see under Edit

Comment: @LithuT.V I was working with addObject:. I tried InsertObject in the end as a desperate measure

Comment: @LithuT.V Arraywitharray doesn't support NSMutableArray(TempArray)  
APP CRASHED

Answer (score 0):

With this line you are creating a new Array every time.

```
NSMutableArray *FileID = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Comment: Please check the edit in the question